# Angular2 : Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors: 'login' is not a known element

Tags: angular, authentication, firebase, firebase-authentication

What I'm trying to do is create login with Firebase Authentication for Angular2 project. When I try to do that, I got this error :

```
Unhandled Promise rejection:

Template parse errors: 'login' is not a known element:
1. If 'login' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'login' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schema' of this component to suppress this message. ("
which comes from a direct reference to the DB child
<em>static</em></strong>: {{direct}}   <hr/>   [ERROR ->]<login
*ngIf='!isAuth'></login>   <div *ngIf='isAuth'>
    <h3>Nicely done!</h3> "): AppComponent@18:2 'logout' is not a known element:
1. If 'logout' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'logout' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schema' of this component to suppress this message. ("
    <p><strong>Your private message:</strong> {{private}}</p>
    <hr/>
    [ERROR ->]<logout></logout>   </div>"): AppComponent@23:4

; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Template parse
errors: 'login' is not a known element: 1. If 'login' is an Angular
component, then verify that it is part of this module. 2. If 'login'
is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the
'@NgModule.schema' of this component to suppress this message. ("
which comes from a direct reference to the DB child
<em>static</em></strong>: {{direct}} <hr/> [ERROR ->]<login
*ngIf='!isAuth'></login> <div *ngIf='isAuth'> <h3>Nicely done!</h3> "): AppComponent@18:2 'logout' is not a known element: 1. If 'logout'
is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'logout' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schema' of this component to suppress this message. ("
<p><strong>Your private message:</strong> {{private}}</p> <hr/> [ERROR
->]<logout></logout> </div>"): AppComponent@23:4

TemplateParser</TemplateParser.prototype.parse@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:15261:19
RuntimeCompiler</RuntimeCompiler.prototype._compileTemplate@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:33617:30
RuntimeCompiler</RuntimeCompiler.prototype._compileComponents/compile/<@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:33540:77
RuntimeCompiler</RuntimeCompiler.prototype._compileComponents/compile@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:33540:37
Zone$1</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:64951:19
Zone$1</Zone</Zone.prototype.run@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:64844:24
scheduleResolveOrReject/<@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:65210:52
Zone$1</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:64984:23
Zone$1</Zone</Zone.prototype.runTask@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:64884:28
drainMicroTaskQueue@http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:65116:25
```

Here is my project structure:

[image]

Here is my `app.component.ts`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from './data.service';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { LoginComponent } from '../app/login/login.component';
import { LogoutComponent } from '../app/logout/logout.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [DataService, UserService]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';

  public message: string;
  public direct: string;
  public private: string;
  public isAuth: boolean;

  constructor (private _data: DataService, private _user: UserService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
      this._user.auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => this.isAuth = !!user);

      // this method...
      this._data.db.child('static').on('value', data => {
        this.message = data.val();
      });

      // ...fetches the same data as this method
      this._data.staticData.on('value', data => {
        this.direct = data.val();
      });

      this._data.db.child('private').on('value', data => {
        this.private = data.val();
      });
    }
}
```

Here is my login module `data.service.ts`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
    public db: any;
    public staticData: any;
    constructor() {
        this.db = firebase.database().ref('/');
        this.staticData = firebase.database().ref('/static');
    }
}
```

What did I miss here? How to solve the error?

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming that the problem you're having is when running your tests? If so, K3v1n's answer probably isn't too far off. The problem you have is that the components aren't being declared by your test module.

You've used ng generate component which automatically adds the declaration to your app.module module, that will (should) be working fine. Now when using  component in the HTML of another component you are testing it doesn't exist.

In the setup of your test you'll be creating a fake module to limit the scope of your test with TestBed;

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({})
```

If you're testing your AppComponent that will probably look like:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
});
```

That's you creating a new module, declaring the component AppComponent as part of the module and testing it. This new module has no knowledge if your login component, it's irrelevant that your app.module does.
In order to fix add the component you're dependent on into the decleration of your test module.

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are the `login` and `logout` components defined by firebase or made by you?

If by firebase, then you forgot to import the firebase module and declare it in the module imports.

If by you, you haven't added them to your module's declarations array.

Cheers!

Comment: it's made by me using "ng generate component login" and "ng generate component logout"

Comment: where is the module imports?

Comment: you mean at app.module.ts?

Comment: @KeVin yes. in the @NgModule definition, there are two arrays: `declarations` and `imports`. Put the generated components in the declarations :)

Answer (score 0):

If the error arises when we are providing templeteUrl instead of templete inline html, then its because of the relative path, you can resolve by putting,

```
moduleId: module.id
```

So,

```
moduleId: module.id,
selector: 'selector',
templateUrl: 'relative-url'
```

> `moduleId` is used to resolve relative paths for your stylesheets and templates as it says in the documentation